# How to extract/decompress this multi-part zip file in Linux?

Tags: linux, zip, extract, compression

I have a zip file thats titled like so file1.zip,file2.zip,file3.zip,etc...

How do I go about extracting these files together correctly? They should produce one output file.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

First, rename them to "file.zip", "file.z01", "file.z02", etc. as Info-ZIP expects them to be named, and then unzip the first file. Info-ZIP will iterate through the split files as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. I had to mount the remote machines user home folder on my Ubuntu desktop pc and use File Roller Archive Manager, which is just listed as Archive Manger in Ubuntu 18.

**Mount remote home folder on local machine...**
*Install sshfs*

```
sudo apt install sshfs
```

**Make a directory for the mount. Replace remote with whatever folder name you want**

```
mkdir remote
```

**Mount the remote file system locally replacing linuxusername with the user account you want to use to login and xxx.* with its IP address or hostname.**

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other  linuxusername@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/ remote
```

Now in the mounted "remote" folder you can see the contents of the whole linux filesystem and navigate them in a File Manager just like your local file system, limited by user privileges of course where you can only write to the home folder of the remote user account.

Using Archive Manager I openened up the .zip file of the spanned set (not the .z01, .z02 etc files) and extracted inside the "remote" folder. I saw no indication of extraction progress, the bar stayed at 0% until it was complete. Other X Windows based archive applications might work.

This is slow, about 3-5 megabytes per second on my LAN. I noticed Archive Manager use 7z to extract but do not know how as 7z is not supposed to support spanned sets.

Also if your ssh server is dropbear instead of openssl's sshd it will be unbearably slow for large files. I had to extract a 160gb archive and the source filesystem was fat32 so was not able to combine the spanned set into one zip file as it has a 4gb file size limit.